# Generate glossary based on acronym reference

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I expect the following code to auto generate a glossary beside the acronym list. However only the acronym list is generated although it contains references to the glossary.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[
    toc,                % Shows glossary in the table of content
    xindy,              % Used superior indexing tool
    acronym,
    nopostdot,
    nostyles,
    ]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries         % used to generate the glossary

\newglossaryentry{fab region}{
   type        = \acronymtype,
   name        = {fab region},
   description = {fragment antigen-binding region},
   first       = {fragment antigen-binding region (fab region)},
   see         = {[Glossary:]{gls:fab region}}
}

\newglossaryentry{gls:fab region}{
    name= Fab region,
    description={The fragment antigen-binding region binds antigens. It is composed of the antibody's light chains and parts of the heavy chains}
}

\begin{document}

This is a test \gls{fab region}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype] % prints just the list of acronyms 
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

I compile the document as following:

```
pdflatex
makeglossaries
pdflatex
pdflatex
```

How do I achieve that the reference from the acronym list adds the referenced entry to the glossary list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only referenced (indexed) `fab region` in the document. If you want `gls:fab region` to also appear in the list then you need to index that as well. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[
    toc,                % Shows glossary in the table of content
    xindy,              % Used superior indexing tool
    acronym,
    nopostdot,
    %nostyles
    ]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries         % used to generate the glossary

\newglossaryentry{fab region}{
   type        = \acronymtype,
   name        = {fab region},
   description = {fragment antigen-binding region},
   first       = {fragment antigen-binding region (fab region)},
   see         = [Glossary:]{gls:fab region}
}

\newglossaryentry{gls:fab region}{
    name= Fab region,
    description={The fragment antigen-binding region binds antigens. It is composed of the antibody's light chains and parts of the heavy chains}
}

\begin{document}

This is a test \gls{fab region}\glsadd{gls:fab region}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype] % prints just the list of acronyms 
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

I've commented out the `nostyles` option because there must be at least one style defined and you haven't provided an alternative. With `nostyles` present, the log file should contain some warnings about it.

[image: Acronyms fab region fragment antigen-binding region 1, Glossary: Fab region]

[image: Glossary Fab region The fragment antigen-binding region binds antigens. It is composed of the antibody’s light chains and parts of the heavy chains 1]

This does seem unnecessary duplication. It would be simpler to just do:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[
    toc,                % Shows glossary in the table of content
    xindy,              % Used superior indexing tool
    nopostdot,
    %nostyles
    ]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries         % used to generate the glossary

\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}

\newacronym[
  description={The fragment antigen-binding region binds antigens. It is composed of the antibody's light chains and parts of the heavy chains}
]{fab region}{fab region}{fragment antigen-binding region}

\begin{document}

This is a test \gls{fab region}.

\printglossary[style=altlist]

\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image: This is a test fragment antigen-binding region (fab region).]

Page 2:

[image: Glossary fragment antigen-binding region (fab region) The fragment antigen-binding region binds antigens. It is composed of the antibody’s light chains and parts of the heavy chains 1]

If you absolutely need a dual-entry system that automatically indexes the related term, you might want to consider using the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) with [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) (instead of `xindy`).

For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{filecontents*}{entries.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8

@dualabbreviationentry{fab-region,
  short = {fab region},
  long = {fragment antigen-binding region},
  description={The fragment antigen-binding region binds antigens. It is composed of the antibody's light chains and parts of the heavy chains}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    record,% use bib2gls
    abbreviations % create 'abbreviations' list
    ]{glossaries-extra}


\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src=entries % data in the file entries.bib
]

\begin{document}

This is a test \gls{fab-region}.

\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations,title=Acronyms]
\printunsrtglossary

\end{document}
```

If the file is called `myDoc.tex` then the document build is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

or if you want the glossary separated into letter groups:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls -g myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

Page 1 as before. Page 2:

[image: Acronyms fab region fragment antigen-binding region 1]

Page 3:

[image: Glossary fragment antigen-binding region The fragment antigen-binding region binds antigens. It is composed of the antibody’s light chains and parts of the heavy chains]

If you want the cross-reference:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{filecontents*}{entries.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8

@dualabbreviationentry{fab-region,
  short = {fab region},
  long = {fragment antigen-binding region},
  description={The fragment antigen-binding region binds antigens. It is composed of the antibody's light chains and parts of the heavy chains}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    record,% use bib2gls
    abbreviations % create 'abbreviations' list
    ]{glossaries-extra}


\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src=entries, % data in the file entries.bib
 dual-field % create a field called 'dual' for cross-referencing
]

\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescabbreviation}{%
  \ifglshasfield{dual}{\glscurrententrylabel}
  {%
  .\space
  \emph{Glossary:} \glshyperlink{\glsxtrusefield{\glscurrententrylabel}{dual}}.%
  }%
 {}%
}

\begin{document}

This is a test \gls{fab-region}.

\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations,title=Acronyms]
\printunsrtglossary

\end{document}
```

Page 2 now looks like:

[image: Acronyms fab region fragment antigen-binding region. Glossary: fab region. 1]

This puts the reference before the location list rather than after it (as in the first example).